# Include 3rd party JS library in webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to include a [thrid-party library](https://javascript.daypilot.org/try/). I am using **webpack** and **angular 2+** for my application, and need to know what would be the way of how I could get a reference to the object in this library.

My angular 2 component,`

```
///<reference path="../../js/daypilot-all.min.d.ts" />

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import DayPilot = require('../../js/daypilot-all.min.js');


@Component({
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        var dp = new DayPilot.DayPilot.Scheduler("dp");

        //dp is an empty object.
        debugger;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the NPM version : https://npm.daypilot.org/

And then you can `import` it as a module.

Comment: Hi basarat, I am using that version, but it does not have all the functionallity that i need from the JS version. Hence my attempt to incorportate the JS version with my app. What would be the process of adding a JS lib to a webpack configured application?

Answer (score 0):

You can define it in the `index.html` like a normal script link:

```
<head>
    <script src="path/js/daypilot-all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

or if you are using `angular-cli` define it in the `assets` property array.

```
"assets": [
   'path/js/daypilot-all.min.js'
];
```

and then in your typescript file you can use the declare keyword.

```
declare var dayPilot: DayPilot;
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        var dp = new dayPilot().Scheduler("dp")
    }
}
```

I don't know what DayPilot contains so `var dp = new dayPilot().Scheduler("dp")` is just an example.